# Como adicionar novas informações no XML usando serialização sem substituir as informações anteriores

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2019

Boa noite pessoal, estou estudando c# casualmente e criando umas aplicações, cheguei em um ponto que preciso criar uma XML com valores, e que cada vez que eu insira informações ele vá para o arquivo XML sem apagar as informações anteriores.

estou utilizando algo bem simples no codigo:

```
public string file = "XML.xml";
public class Pessoas
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
}
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Pessoas p = new Pessoas() { Nome = "Fulano", Idade = 50 };
    XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Pessoas));
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file);
    xml.Serialize(writer, p);
    writer.Close();
}
```

ele gera um arquivo XML padrão, mas sempre que mudo o valor do nome e idade no codigo ele modifica o que ja foi inputado arquivo.

Comment: A ideia aí seria você usar um Reader, tacar o que está no arquivo pra dentro de um objeto/coleção em memória.. fazer suas modificações e depois escrever o objeto alterado no arquivo, subscrevendo, mas incluindo o que já havia.

Mas recomento que utilize JSON, que é um formato muito mais utilizado que XML, no geral.

Comment: Entendi, estou vendo json como me sugeriu, achei bem tranquilo de se trabalhar, vc tem algum material de apoio pra me indicar ?

Comment: Você não pode utilizar nenhum tipo de banco de dados para isso? Persistir as informações da sua aplicação em um arquivo de texto é uma péssima ideia e um belo convite para ter problemas de concorrência e até perda de dados.